# React JS - accessing component property in an element attribute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, render, custom-attribute

I have an element defined as class, and in the `render()` method I'm trying to give an element a custom attribute `data-activates` with an id. However, in the resulting html I just see the plaintext of the expression, either one of the following:

`data-activates="{this.state._id}"`

`data-activates="${this.state._id}"`

`data-activates="{id}"`

`data-activates="${id}"`

The id is present in both `props` and `state`, and outside of the element both of them work correctly:

`<a className="dropdown-button waves-effect" href="#!" data-activates="{id}">`

`{ id }, {this.state._id}` <- works here

`</a>`

For some reason React doesn't resolve expressions within the attribute and I need that for the dropdown to work. What am I doing wrong?

Bonus point for a better way to implement dropdown in React, if there is no way to make this code work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to go into JavaScript land inside your JSX with the help of `{}`. That way you can use any expression you like in the JSX.

**Example**

```
<a
  className="dropdown-button waves-effect"
  href="#"
  data-activates={this.state._id}
>
  Test
</a>
```

Comment: Indeed, the quotes were excessive, the working variant is: ` data-activates={'post_dropdown_'+id}` in my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should not wrap `data` attributes inside `QUOTES`

```
data-activates={this.state._id}
data-activates={id}
```

This documentation clears everything [check the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#javascript-expressions)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have tried the following:

```
<a data-activates={this.state._id}>...</a>
<a data-activates={id}>...</a>
```

Please bear in mind that JSX adheres to JS syntax first. So inside the curly brackets, you still can do interpolation within tildes (`):

```
<a data-activates={`my-id-${id}`}>...</a>
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a dash. Use lowerCamelCase instead. React doesn't recognize elements with a dash in the name as a prop. So, instead of `data-activates={id}`, use `dataActivates={id}`.

Comment: Wrong, React will parse that into meaningless `dataactivates=`, without the dash. This attribute is an exception that doesn't follow the camelCase.

Comment: Sorry. When you said "define element" I thought you mean you were creating a custom component.